# Google Chrome parse error on closing form tag

Tags: html, google-chrome

I get a HTML parse error (recovered gracefully) warning on my console whenever I have a form with a closing tag.

So this gives a parsing error:

```
 <body>
    <form>
      ...some_form_fields
    </form>
  </body>
```

While this doesnt:

```
 <body>
    <form>
      ...some_form_fields
  </body>
```

This seems very weird. I checked the HTML 5 specs and there's nothing about closing form tags being forbidden. In fact, they are required.

I am using HTML 5 doctype. Google Chrome 11.

UPDATE: I tested using this very bare HTML and it still gives the warning

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: No warning for me: Chrome 9.0.597.107

Comment: You should provide more detailed description of your problem and post more code. We don't see a mistake yet, it seems to be between `form` tags.

Comment: Edit your question with the code of a complete HTML file with which this happens.

Comment: I added a complete HTML file.

Comment: Try disabling your Chrome extensions, I'm unable to reproduce on Chrome 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything (relevant) wrong.

See this bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73703

The test case in the issue is almost identical to yours:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/79816

> This patch removes parse error
>   messages from the HTML parser. These
>   messages are displayed at the wrong
>   times, aren't tested, and aren't
>   helpful. We'll try again with some
>   more informative messages and better
>   testing.